# Why did Chief Bromden fool everyone?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, one-flew-over-the-cuckoos-nest

In [One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073486/), at the beginning of the movie we're told that Chief is a deaf and dumb. However, when McMurphy and Chief were talking just before the electroshock therapy scene, we came to know that Chief is not a deaf and dumb and he can talk.

So, what made him to fool the doctors? Is that just to escape from nurse Ratched's therapy? I believe the movie adapted from a novel, so, Is anything mentioned in the novel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [source novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Flew_Over_the_Cuckoo%27s_Nest_(novel)), he pretends to be deaf and dumb because it  allows him to hear the secrets of the people around him.

> *They laugh and then I hear them mumbling behind me, heads close
>   together. Hum of black machinery, humming hate and death and other
>   hospital secrets. They don’t bother not talking out loud about their
>   hate secrets when I’m nearby because they think I’m deaf and dumb.
>   Everybody thinks so. I’m cagey enough to fool them that much. If my
>   being half Indian ever helped me in any way in this dirty life, it
>   helped me being cagey, helped me all these years.*

This odd behaviour stems from his childhood and beyond:

> *It hadn’t been just since I came in the hospital, either; people first
>   took to acting like I couldn’t hear or talk a long time before that.
>   In the Army anybody with more stripes acted that way toward me. That
>   was the way they figured you were supposed to act around someone
>   looked like I did. And even as far back as grade school I can remember
>   people saying that they didn’t think I was listening, so they quit
>   listening to the things I was saying.*